# Insert Date value in SQL Express in visual studio 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm using SQL Express in visual studio 2013.

I have table name [Orders]

It has the following columns : Id , orderDate and customerId.

the question is : how can I  define orderDate to take the exact time automatically.

i want it in the definition of the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order] (
    [Id]         INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [orderDate]  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [customerId] INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_order_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([customerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

You can Use [DEFAULT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) Values to Insert into Tables

```
alter table Orders add orderDate Datetime DEFAULT (GETDATE())


CREATE TABLE Orders
(

orderDate Datetime DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Comment: i want it in the definition of the table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order] (
    [Id]         INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [orderDate]  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [customerId] INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_order_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([customerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])

Answer (score 0):

You can use GETDATE() directly in your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO Orders (Id , orderDate, customerId) VALUES (@id,GETDATE(),@customerid)
```

Directly in table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order] 
( [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
  [orderDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()), 
  [customerId] INT NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_order_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([customerId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
```